# Java method extension instead of overwriting

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

Is there some type of @annotation, or other method, in Java to enforce method extension, instead of overriding?

To be specific, let's say I have a class Foo:

```
class Foo {
    public void bar(Thing thing) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can enforce, at compile time, that any class X that extends Foo, and also overrides bar, makes a call to `super.bar(thing)` first?

Comment: You could probably do that with an annotation processor.

Comment: @Rob perhaps create an `@Extend` annotation to use in place of `@Override`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to explicitly write it.

Side note for constructors: the superclass' nullary constructor will be implicitly called when instantiating the subclass, however many parameters the latter's constructor has.

Comment: note, nullary constructor is implicitly called only when no other constructor is called explicetly (you can call another constructor both from superclass and this class).

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov ...and a nullary constructor must be available in the super class (either explicitly, or by defining no constructors at all), and it must not be `private`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, what you can do is to create a `final` method, that calls the extendable one.

```
class Foo {

    @Override
    public final void bar(Thing thing) {
        // super code comes here
        this.doBar(thing);
    }

    public abstract void doBar(Thing thing);

}
```

When you call

```
foo.bar(thing);
```

your super code runs first, then the code from the child class.

This way you can protect your full `bar` logic, and allow only certain parts to be extended/reimplemented.

Also, it allows you to *postprocess* the result, or to *break up* your code to certain subtasks.

Comment: I use this sort of pattern all the time, the problem is that it doesn't work for > 1 levels of inheritance.  The `doBar` method would have the same contract/problem as the original `bar` method, or you would have to start a `doDoBar`, `doDoDoBar`, ... paradigm.

Comment: @torquestomp that's true, better try to find a proper name for the wrapped logic. Actually I never had to use it in multiple layers.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare `bar` to be `final`, then call an abstract method from `bar`, which would force subclasses to implement an "extension".

```
abstract class Foo {
    public final void bar(Thing thing) {
        barImpl(thing);
        overrideMe(thing);
    }

    private final void barImpl(Thing thing) {
        // Original implementation of "bar" here.
    }

    protected abstract void overrideMe(Thing thing);
}
```

**EDIT**

I've changed`overrideMe` from `public` to `protected` so users of `Foo` can't just call `overrideMe` instead of `bar`.

Comment: Like I noted on GaborSch's answer, this method only delays the problem somewhat.  If there is a second level of inheritance, the `overrideMe` method acquires the exact same problem as the original `bar` method.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot force code to call up to its superclass at compile time, it's not too hard to detect at run time when code does not call up to the superclass.

```
class Foo {
    private boolean baseCalled;
    public final void bar(Thing thing) {
        baseCalled = false;
        barImp(thing);
        if (!baseCalled) {
            throw new RuntimeException("super.barImp() not called");
        }
    }
    protected void barImp(Thing thing) {
         baseCalled = true;
         . . . // base class implementation of bar
    }
}
```

Note that this extends to multiple levels of inheritance without further elaboration. The method works particularly well for methods that are called from within `Foo`; in those cases, you can often forgo the `final` qualifier and redirection to an implementation method, and just define the base class method to set the flag. Clearing the flag would be done at each point of invocation.

The above pattern is used extensively in the Android framework. It doesn't guarantee that `super.barImp` was called as the *first thing* in subclass overrides; just that it was called.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `@AroundInvoke` annotation, if you are using EJBs.

By using reflection, you can find the same method in your *parent* class, and yo can invoke it with the same parameters as the original method was called.

Note, that in this case you must avoid `super.bar(thing)` calls, otherwise they would be called twice.